# Обновление записи в json массиве

Tags: php, массивы, json

Есть json массив

```
{"vname":"\u0418\u0438\u0438","src":"http:\/\/video.sibnet.ru\/shell.php?videoid=3291274","desc":"\u041e\u043e\u043e\u0440\u043e","date":"2018-30-05 11:07:14","comments":[],"like":0,"dislike":0,"likeid":["-1","-2"],"dislikeid":["-1","-2"]}
```

Как обновить в нем записи `like` и `likeid` с помощью php?

Я сейчас делаю так:

```
$ndislikes = [
            "dislike" => $like,
            "dislikeid" => $adlid
        ];
        $ndislikes = json_encode($ndislikes);
        file_put_contents("../json/".$idv.".json", $ndislikes);
```

Да, тогда записывается новое значение в эти строки, но все остальные значения исчезают, так вот как обновить значения `like` и `likeid`, что бы другие значения не стирались?, Например , привести массив к такому виду:

```
{"vname":"\u0418\u0438\u0438","src":"http:\/\/video.sibnet.ru\/shell.php?videoid=3291274","desc":"\u041e\u043e\u043e\u0440\u043e","date":"2018-30-05 11:07:14","comments":[],"like":1,"dislike":0,"likeid":["-1","-2", "11"],"dislikeid":["-1","-2"]}
```

Comment: А как насчет достать, перевести в php `json_decode()`, заменить переменные и снова перекодировать и записать данные в файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '{"vname":"\u0418\u0438\u0438","src":"http:\/\/video.sibnet.ru\/shell.php?videoid=3291274","desc":"\u041e\u043e\u043e\u0440\u043e","date":"2018-30-05 11:07:14","comments":[],"like":0,"dislike":0,"likeid":["-1","-2"],"dislikeid":["-1","-2"]}';

$arr = json_decode($string, true);

$dislike = 1337; // @type integer
$dislikeid = [228, 1488]; // @type array

list($arr['dislike'], $arr['dislikeid']) = [$dislike, $dislikeid];

echo json_encode($arr);
```